# Angular JS - load a custom directive based on current scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I'd like to achieve is a reusable tabbed element that can load in a custom directive based on the current active tab. A directive within a directive.

I've built the tab wrapper element and have got the tabs to update $scope.activeTab, and inside this element I've hard-coded .

What I'd like to do is to have the tabs dictate which directive is inside, so it could be description-element, or image-element, or meta-element etc...

I could easily accomplish this by writing all the elements inside the tab wrapper when it loads and then use ng-hide to toggle them as the tabs are clicked, but I'd really like to be able to AJAX in the content and replace what is there when the tabs change.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be after ng-switch http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

It will remove from the DOM the elements that don't match the condition.

```
<div ng-switch on="item">
    <div ng-switch-when="image"><image-directive /></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="meta"><meta-directive /></div>
</div>

controllers.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.item = data.elementType;
    }).
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's a big improvement on what I had originally, but it still relies on the directives I want to put in the tab switcher being explicitly written in to it.


I'd like the tab switcher to be reusable in multiple situations, so it would be great if the switching of a tab could trigger the insertion of a dynamically designated directive. i.e. clicking the 'image' tab would load then render $scope.activeTab + '-directive' into the DOM.

Comment: I'm just beginning to look at $compile - would that do what I need?

Comment: Then you're probably looking to use $compile and actually compiling the directive dynamically into the DOM. I personally don't think it's a good approach, ng-switch contains all of the generic parts you need, adding a dynamic directive name is likely to make your code fragile.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Eddie. So you'd recommend creating an individual directive for each tab switcher I'll need across the app, rather than a reusable component?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish but generally I'd look to be more declarative. ng-switch does all of your re-usable tabbing, it seems to make sense to be declarative about what content should be shown based on what condition.